# class constructor

Tags: php, constructor

I am trying to understand how classes and functions work more.
So i have written a class with 2 functions inside it. Then initiated the class with

```
$fifaadmin = new FifaAdmin;
```

When I try to call this class from another page i get the following error

> Call to a member function leagueToReplace() on a non-object

What am i doing wrong? Is there an obvious answer?
Thanks

Comment: You need to supply more code context - show the class definitions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `$fifaadmin` didn't instantiate the object correctly.

What does this say?

```
var_dump($fifaadmin instanceof FifaAdmin);
```

It should return `true` if it is set up correctly. Try it just before you call a method on it.

When you say *another page*, do you mean from a PHP include or a new URL (and therefore request)?

You will need to instantiate it on every request, as HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Returns false! 
On another page, like an include file yeah.
The fifaadmin is a class on a page called fifaadmin.php which is an include. 
When i say $fifaadmin->method1(); it should use that method.

Comment: Ensure that the class definition is included before you attempt to make an instance of the object.

Comment: That is also true in the case you save an object of a custom class in the PHP session.

Comment: Hey, yeah I wasnt including the file!
Fixed now. THanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the class on each page. Each script is executed independently.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your code does, you might want to use [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) methods:

```
// common.php
class Common {
    public static function calculate($x, $y) {
        return $x + $y;
    }
}

// another PHP file: (you still need to include common.php
// you won't need to instantiate the class

echo Common::calculate(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an instance of class in different pages, you need to serialize it and save it somewhere (session is ok) and de-serialize it when you want use it.

More detail about serialize in PHP here http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php